# Google Maps infowindow.setContent conditionals

Tags: jquery, google-maps, conditional-statements

I am creating some Google Map markers from JSON and I want to format the content using shorthand if statements. Here is what I have right now:

```
infowindow.setContent('<strong>' + this.title + '</strong>' + this.description + '<a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank">Website</a>');
```

All markers will have a title, but some might have a description but not a link or a link but not a description. How can I make it so that if the marker has a link and description it will look like above, if it has a link but no description it will look like this:

```
infowindow.setContent('<strong>' + this.title + '</strong>' + '<br/>' + '<a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank">Website</a>');
```

Or like this if it has a description but not a link:

```
infowindow.setContent('<strong>' + this.title + '</strong>' + this.description );
```

I know I could just set up 3 different `infowindow.setContent` functions, but I was wondering if there was a way to use inline conditional statements to do it with one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ternary operator

```
infowindow.setContent('<strong>' + this.title + '</strong>' + 
    ( this.description =='' ?  ('<br/><a href="' + this.link +
        '" target="_blank">Website</a>') : this.description))  ;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! You are missing a `)` before the semi-colon, but it's working as desired after adding that.

Comment: @user13286   ... many thanks  .. answer updated  with  ) before semicolon